# How can I display blockly in HTML outside of a browser?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, blockly

I'm trying to display [Blockly](https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/get-started/web) in an application which takes HTML Data in JS' `return` statement, I've attempted multiple things and followed the [setup guide](https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/configure/web/fixed-size).
This is the code I ended up with:

```
      <script src="file:///C:/Users/Daniel%20Neim/Desktop/Underground%20Raw%20Data/google-blockly/google-blockly-7426010/blockly_compressed.js"></script><script src="file:///C:/Users/Daniel%20Neim/Desktop/Underground%20Raw%20Data/google-blockly/google-blockly-7426010/blocks_compressed.js">
      </script><script src="file:///C:/Users/Daniel%20Neim/Desktop/Underground%20Raw%20Data/google-blockly/google-blockly-7426010/msg/js/en.js"></script>

      <xml id="toolbox">
        <block type="controls_if"></block>
        <block type="controls_repeat_ext"></block>
        <block type="logic_compare"></block>
        <block type="math_number"></block>
        <block type="math_arithmetic"></block>
        <block type="text"></block>
        <block type="text_print"></block>
      </xml>
        <div id="blocklyDiv" style="height: 400px; width: 712px;"></div>


        <script>
        var workspace = Blockly.inject('blocklyDiv',
              {toolbox: document.getElementById('toolbox')});
        </script>
```

As far as I know, I'm referencing the correct local files and doing everything right, yet it's **entirely blank**. I've changed the order of the `<div>` and `<xml>`, tried using upwards directories `../google-blockly/google-blockly7426010/blockly_compressed.js`.

I think the issue with the scripts, but I'm not sure so I'd highly appreciate if someone helped me out.

Comment: Have you checked Console in Developer Tools?

Comment: It works like this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ogLu89cj/ So my guess is that the script URLs are bad. Use relative paths.

Comment: @ChrisG Still nothing, despite using your jsfiddle with relative URLs, even located within the same folder.

Comment: @MaximMazurok I don't have access to Developer Tools in said app, "Discord Bot Maker", I have an extremely rudimentary log, which doesn't tell me much here.

Comment: Hit view > developer > developer tools > console.

Comment: This is tagged node.js but you're using browser code. I'm confused as to what the build setup is here, as well as the expected workflow/result.